# Redirect request to another url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my action I have `Request` property. I want to use this request to get response from another URL (from **another website**). Is it possible?

Comment: "I want to use this request to get response from another URL" - you mean another website or just another action content?

Comment: what do you mean by response from other site? do you mean redirect or just get something from other site?

Comment: Redirect current request to another website and get response by this request, of course.

Comment: the redirection must be server side or you can have a proper redirect ? In the first case, I suggest you to perform manually the HTTP Get and write its response on your controller response, otherwise you can use a RedirectResult (url, permanent) in your action

Comment: Is it possible to save form data and coockiens from existing `Request` in your solution?

Answer (score -1):

To request a external webpage from C# code and retrieve it as a string. You can use the following snippet of code:

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.steelcm.com/");
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        // Convert stream object to string
        string myWebPage = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    // TODO: Handle error exception
}
```

This will return the HTML in the string variable myWebPage. Also you will need to include the following 2 libraries:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

Of course you can manipulate the request URL dependant on a users input.